# Android testing of the floating view

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I add a floating view to the WindowManager, and make it movable around the screen, and i can perform click event when i click this view, everything works fine.

However, I don't know how to **access this view in espresso or UIAutomator**.

### Add view to WindowManager

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    type,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            );

            ImageView floatingView = new ImageView(mContext);
            floatingView.setContentDescription("bugtags_fab_des_normal");
            mWindowManager.addView(floatingView, layoutParams);
```

### The Floating View

> the white-blue icon in rect is the floating view i am talking about.

[image: floating-view]

### Question

The floating view response a click event, and perform some task, now i want to do this in AndroidJunit test.

- Espresso

I try Espresso, using onView method, but the test case:

```
onView(withContentDescription("bugtags_fab_des_normal")).perform(click());
```

Get:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with content description: is "bugtags_fab_des_normal"
```

- UIAutomator

I try UIAutomator Viewer, but i can't find the floatingView in view hierarchy.

### How

How can i access this view in **espresso or uiautomator** and perform click to it?

### Appendix

#### Test Case

```
@Test
public void testInvoke() {
    onView(withContentDescription("bugtags_fab_des_normal")).perform(click());
}
```

#### Output log

[output-log-gist](https://gist.github.com/kevinho/27d0bd891a331aa954bd)

#### Bugtags.com

Actually, i am using a sdk called [bugtags.com](https://github.com/bugtags/Bugtags-Android), it's a simple tool for app bug reporting and crash analysis.

Comment: could you provide full log of android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException:

Comment: hi, i have already appended testcase and output log.

Comment: hey hey! how did you implement that floating button and handle click events on it? Please provide me its code or link to tutorial please please!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your view is outside of `Activity` so can find it by using `inRoot()` method:

```
@Test
public void checkClickOnFloatingButton() {
    onView(withContentDescription("bugtags_fab_des_normal")).inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))).perform(click());
}
```

Also you probably should change `reportImage` to `floatingView` in this piece of code:

```
ImageView floatingView = new ImageView(mContext);
reportImage.setContentDescription("bugtags_fab_des_normal"); // <---`reportImage` to `floatingView`
mWindowManager.addView(floatingView, layoutParams);
```

Comment: Awesome! It works like a charm! And i like to ask a question, why i should use withDecorView(not()), what is not() here means?

Comment: probably, it will work without `withDecorView(not())`. I didn't try. It is the copy from another project. But as I remember (I may be wrong) with this method we are not searching view in our `Activity` and thus reducing test time.

Comment: ok，i will learn about it further. The bounty will be given to you 22 hours later.

Comment: Is it possible to find this view using UIAutomator ?

Answer (score -1):

Add an onClickListener on your `floatingView`

Comment: sorry, you miss-understand my question, i wan to access this in espresso